# How do I produce asynchronous non blocking messages using libkafka?

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

I have a loop that is producing messages by calling something like this.

```
Client *client; 
client = new Client('127.0.0.1', 9092);
client->sendProduceRequest(new ProduceRequest(correlationId, clientId, requiredAcks, timeout, produceTopicArraySize, produceTopicArray, true));
```

How do I make the sendProduceRequest be non-blocking?

Comment: Which kafka C++ Client library are you using? I am using C++ client too. But we are using different libraries.